# How can I validate that two associated objects have the same parent object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two different objects which can belong to one parent object. These child objects can both also belong to each other (many to many). What's the best way to ensure that child objects which belong to each other also belong to the same parent object.

As an example of what I'm trying to do I have a `Kingdom` which has both many `People` and `Land`. The `People` model would have a custom `validate` which checks each related `Land` and  `error.add`s if one has a mismatched `kingdom_id`. The `Land` model would have a similar `validate`.

This seems to work, but when updating it allows the record to save the `'THIS IS AN ERROR'` error is in `people.errors`, however the `Land` which raised the error has been added to the `People` collection.

```
kingdom = Kingdom.create
people  = People.create(:kingdom => kingdom)
land    = Land.create(:kingdom_id => 999)
people.lands << land
people.save
puts people.errors.inspect # @messages={:base=>["THIS IS AN ERROR"]
puts people.lands.inspect  # [#<Land id: 1...
```

Ideally I'd want the error to cancel the record update. Is there another way I should be going about this, or am I going in the wrong direction entirely?

```
# Models:

class Kingdom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  has_many :lands
end

class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kingdom
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lands

  validates :kingdom_id, :presence => true
  validates :kingdom, :associated => true
  validate  :same_kingdom?

  private
    def same_kingdom?
      if self.lands.any?
        errors.add(:base, 'THIS IS AN ERROR') unless kingdom_match
      end
    end

    def kingdom_match
      self.lands.each do |l|
        if l.kingdom_id != self.kingdom_id
          return false
        end
      end
    end
end

class Land < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kingdom
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
end
```

Comment: Have you try to do `people.reload` and see if lands still have one element ? I don't think it is persisted to the database, just attached to the instance.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois, exactly my point...

Comment: Thank you both. Silly mistake...definitely should have known about the `reload` method by now...

Comment: @PinnyM yup! I upvoted you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the validation won't prevent the record from being added to the model's unpersisted collection.  It will prevent the revised collection from being persisted to the database.  So the model will be in an invalid state, and flagged as such with the appropriate errors.  To see this, you can simply reload the `people` object.

You also have an error in your logic - the `kingdom_match` method will never return true even if no invalid kingdom_id's are found.  You should add a line to fix this:

```
def kingdom_match
  self.lands.each do |l|
    return false if l.kingdom_id != self.kingdom_id
  end
  true
end
```

And you can make this validation a bit more concise and skip the `kingdom_match` method entirely:

```
def same_kingdom?
  if self.lands.any?{|l| l.kingdom_id != self.kingdom_id }
    errors.add(:base, 'THIS IS AN ERROR')
  end
end
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for the explanation and the code cleanup as well.